# Facebook app custom actions

Tags: feed, facebook-apps

I created a customer action for an application, it's approved and it's currently working. When the action is posted on Facebook by an user (User A), it appears on the Recent Activity, not on the User A timeline and it's appearing in some users feed.

Why is appearing in the feed of some users and not on the feed of other users?
Why is not appearing on the User A timeline?

Comment: These kinds of things are not for us to know. It's pretty much internal decisions from within Facebook what stories they feel most interest you. Perhaps a user with more common interests will be displayed more, perhaps mutual friends... At the end of the day I seriously doubt anyone outside of Facebook will be able to know the exact details.

Comment: As such - I'm afraid this post might be too localized. It's not inconceivable that the rules which decide what to display and where are ever-changing and one answer today will be rendered useless the next time FB pushes a new build (which happens often)

Comment: Might be due to his Privacy settings for the Application. Just check them if they are `me only` or some other value

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late to help but adding for posterity…

You need to be sure that "fb:explicitly_shared=true" is set for the action.  If you don't have this set for your custom action, you may need to get it re-approved.

Note this goes on the action itself, not the corresponding graph object.